# ntsecapi.h:594:22: error: expected unqualified-id before string constant

Tags: c++, objective-c, visual-studio-2010, include

I'm building a small project (I'm running windows 7 with cygwin64 ). here is how my "header of program" looks like

```
#ifndef Win32_H
#define Win32_H

#define USE_LSA
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>

#include <psapi.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SECURITY_WIN32
#include <ntstatus.h>

#include <Sspi.h>
#include <Ntsecapi.h>
#include <Ntsecpkg.h>
#include <sddl.h>
#include <algorithm>

#include "Class1.h"

#include "Class2.h"

#include <Class3.h>

#include <errno.h>
```

I downloaded this project to examine. But the problem I have is that I ran into a compiling error which says

```
In file included from /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/Sspi.h:10:0,
             from main.cpp:61:

/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/ntsecapi.h:594:22: error: expected unqualified-id before string constant
typedef LSA_STRING STRING,*PSTRING;
                  ^
In file included from /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/Sspi.h:10:0,
             from TokenServer.cpp:61:
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/ntsecapi.h:707:5: error: expected unqualified-id before string constant
 STRING CaseSensitiveChallengeResponse;
 ^
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/ntsecapi.h:708:5: error: expected unqualified-id before string constant
 STRING CaseInsensitiveChallengeResponse;
 ^
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/ntsecapi.h:718:5: error: expected unqualified-id before string constant
 STRING AuthenticationInfo1;
 ^
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/ntsecapi.h:719:5: error: expected unqualified-id before string constant
 STRING AuthenticationInfo2;
 ^
```

I've googled a little bit but found nothing that would help me [this is the same problem as mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837024/expected-unqualified-id-before-string-constant). and also this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896230/unqualified-id-before-string-constant). But as I've said they didn't help. Hope you can help me. thanks.

Comment: What is the source of your header? Where did you get it from? Cause the one I just found by googling has that line written in the other way: `typedef STRING LSA_STRING, *PLSA_STRING;`

Comment: Its actually a university project I cant upload it here.

Comment: I'm not talking about your project, I'm talking about the package or library that header file came with.

Comment: Sorry If I musunderstand something, but the headers came with project.

Comment: Somewhere in your code, before the inclusion of this header, there is a macro named `STRING`.

Comment: Scratch that. @molbdnilo, is right. My cygwin installation carries the same line in header, so it's indeed a macro somewhere.

Comment: @molbdnilo yes, Thats what I thought but this is a library(.dll) and this file a `main.cpp` where should I search it?

Comment: @Rasty Search for "#define STRING" in your own code.

Comment: I could not find it.